# stretch an object

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a image of a string of size 12*30. I want to create an animation such that it gives a feel of stretching of a string. I did it by scaling the the image but problem I am facing that the collision is not happening with scaled image. It occurs only in 12*30 region which is the size of original image. I want the collision to happen though out the length of the string. Is there a better way than scaling to do this. Thanks.

```
image_rect = display.newImage("string.png")
image_rect.x = frog_jump_SheetSet.x + 10
image_rect.y = frog_jump_SheetSet.y + 10
physics.addBody(image_rect )
image_rect.yScale = 0.1
localGroup:insert(image_rect)

image_rect .collision = onStretch
image_rect :addEventListener("collision",image_rect )

tr1 = tnt:newTransition(image_rect,{time = 50,yScale = string_length })

tr2 = tnt:newTransition(image_rect,{delay = 100,time = 50,yScale = 0.1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona Physics engine do not support scaling directly, the only thing you may do is add rectangles to the object or delete them as needed to fit the new shape...

In general, you should avoid using scaling or rotation of the image when using physics, and instead only change the physics API to rotate (using torque) and there are nothing you can do about scaling.